# How to run multiple 7zip processes sequentially?

Tags: 7-zip

I would like to start multiple 7zip processes, each of which performs a different task. As these processes often work on the same hard disk, I would like them to run sequentially instead of in parallel. How would I go about that?

For comparison, WinRAR does offer this functionality (even though it is slightly bugged).

The processes are started in the file manager (Windows Explorer in my case), not command line, in case there are distinct solutions.

Comment: 7-Zip has a command-line interface (`7z.exe`), and this is the best way to run processes sequentially, though there are utilities to wait for a Windows process and take action on its completion.

Comment: @AFH Yes, I could just put the commands in a batch file. But for convenience I'm looking for a solution that let's me stay in GUI at all times. With WinRAR, the whole process takes me only a few tens of seconds, which is impossible to beat if I have to write down all involved paths and program arguments.